# Procedure for changing organization and project names

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, devops

my company split into 2 and the visual studio online accounts, organization and project names are all pointed to the other company/domain of ours.  I need to move/change these things to reflect the new company/domain.  Anyone out there have a procedure to follow to change the VSO URL, organization and project names?  It's imperative that I do not lose any source control history.

Comment: Do you have a support account with Microsoft? If so you might want to contact them.

Answer (score 1):

1. To rename your organization in Azure DevOps, you need at least **Basic access** and **organization Owner** permissions. And then go to **Organization settings -- Overview** to rename the organization:

   [image]

> **Caution**
>
> The rename operation affects your organization's connections and
>   individuals who are currently working with your organization. Before
>   you start, find out [what to do before and after renaming your
>   organization](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2793597/things-to-do-before-and-after-you-rename-the-url-of-your-team-foundati).

Detailed information, you can refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/rename-organization?view=azure-devops

2. To rename a team project, you need **Rename project** permission for a project. Select **Project settings > Overview**, and then enter a new name and select Save.

   [image]

Useful links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/rename-project?view=azure-devops
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/faq-rename-project?view=azure-devops